# Swing CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, indexing, cardlayout

What is the default behavior of cardlayout when you add two cards with same identifier. For example, if have `panel1` which is added. Later in the program, I add `panel2` with the same string identifier. Is the default behavior to replace `panel1` with `panel2` in the card stack?
Thanks

Comment: try it yourself and you'll see :) ... and I think that you can find it in the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Answer (score 4):

Below is `CardLayout's` implementation of `addLayoutComponent()` which is executed by `addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints)`.

```
public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
    synchronized (comp.getTreeLock()) {
        if (!vector.isEmpty()) {
            comp.setVisible(false);
        }
        for (int i=0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
            if (((Card)vector.get(i)).name.equals(name)) {
                ((Card)vector.get(i)).comp = comp;
                return;
            }
        }
        vector.add(new Card(name, comp));
    }
}
```

`CardLayout` maintains a vector of `Card` objects (see below). Looks like when a name collision is detected, the `Component` in the `Card` with the same name is replaced with new `Component` being added. So, `show()` with a particular name will display the ***last*** component that was added with that name.

```
class Card implements Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 6640330810709497518L;
    public String name;
    public Component comp;
    public Card(String cardName, Component cardComponent) {
        name = cardName;
        comp = cardComponent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You *can* add multiple cards with the same identifier.  You can [edit]***only***<strike>still</strike>[/edit] navigate to <strike>both</strike>.  `show(Container, String)` shows the panel added [edit]<strike>first</strike>***last***[/edit].

Kasper